# Multiple Word Matches (Full Text) In single or multiple documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, solr, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

My requirement is this:

**If I pass multiple words for search as a list, ES will return documents with subset of word  matches along with words matched So I can understand which document matched which subset.**

Suppose I need to search for words such as Football, Cricket, Tennis, Golf etc.
in  three  documents

I am going to store these files in corresponding documents. Mappings for "mydocuments" index looks like this:

```
{
  "mydocuments" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "docs" : {
        "properties" : {
          "file_content" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First Document

```
{ _id: 1, file_content: "I love tennis and cricket"}
```

Second document:

```
{ _id: 2, file_content: "tennis and football are very popular"}
```

Third document:

```
{ _id: 3, file_content: "football and cricket are originated in england"}
```

> I should be able to search a single file/or multiple files for Football, Tennis,
>   cricket, golf and it should return something like this

Something like this

```
    "hits":{
        "total" : 3,
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "twitter",
                "_type" : "tweet",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_source" : {
                    "file_content" : ["football","cricket"],
                    "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",

                }
                },
                {
                    "_index" : "twitter",
                    "_type" : "tweet",
                    "_id" : "2",
                    "_source" : {
                        "file_content" : ["football","tennis"],
                        "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",

                    }
                }
            ]
```

Or in case of multiple file searches an array of above search results

Any idea how can we do this using Elasticsearch?

If this really can not be done using elasticsearch I am ready to evaluate any other options (Native lucene, Solr)

**EDIT**

My bad probably I did not provide enough details. @Andrew what I meant by file is the text content of a file stored as a String Field (Full Text) in a document in ES. Assume One file corresponds to one document with text content string in a field called "file_content".

Comment: I think you need to think about your own application and see what ES can give you and what you can do to arrange the results in the way you want **in your own application**. `{football: yes, cricket: no, tennis : yes , golf no}` is about your application and ES cannot give you something like this. ES gives you JSON and this JSON has a certain, well determined structure. Please read the documentation about ES first, and then come up with a meaningful question about ES.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: I do find the question interesting and regard it as a generic ES question. (Disclaimer: I’m a Solr user.) The text from the files are tokenized, and I’d say the question boils down to: *If I give a number of words to ES, how can I find out which of these words (or tokens generated from the words) are in which document?* I don’t think the original poster needs exactly the given JSON structure, but merely data that can be derived from the JSON structure returned by ES.

Comment: @BlueM, first of all he talks about "files". In ES we talk about documents. How he/she went from "file" to "document" - no mention about this. Secondly, there is no mapping, you assume "tokenized". Ok, tokenized how? Does he already have a mapping, if so where is it? Can the poster clarify the JSON statement I made? Nothing so far. Thirdly, fyi SO has some [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. These being said, I do expect the poster to show what he tried, what he has so far and what doesn't work. I gave him/her an important advice about reading docs.

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Sure – there are a lot of details missing in the question, and for simplicity’s sake I’ve made certain assumptions about the setup. But still: I’d be interested in the answer :-)

Comment: @BlueM Ok. Assuming so many things qualifies as a "Too broad" type of question for SO. I will wait for updates to the post. Until then I will not attempt an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you can get to what you want is [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html), meaning emphasizing the searched terms in the documents.

Sample query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "file_content": "football tennis cricket golf"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {"file_content":{}}
  }
}
```

Result:

```
       "hits": {
          "total": 3,
          "max_score": 0.027847305,
          "hits": [
             {
                "_index": "test_highlight",
                "_type": "docs",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.027847305,
                "_source": {
                   "file_content": "I love tennis and cricket"
                },
                "highlight": {
                   "file_content": [
                      "I love <em>tennis</em> and <em>cricket</em>"
                   ]
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "test_highlight",
                "_type": "docs",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.023869118,
                "_source": {
                   "file_content": "tennis and football are very popular"
                },
                "highlight": {
                   "file_content": [
                      "<em>tennis</em> and <em>football</em> are very popular"
                   ]
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "test_highlight",
                "_type": "docs",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.023869118,
                "_source": {
                   "file_content": "football and cricket are originated in england"
                },
                "highlight": {
                   "file_content": [
                      "<em>football</em> and <em>cricket</em> are originated in england"
                   ]
                }
             }
          ]
       }
```

As you can see the terms that were found are highlighted (elements surrounded by `<em>` tags) under a special `highlight` section.